# Opening browser and opening a particular website on ionic framework

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

Hi I would like to ask how will I be able to open a browser and going to a particular website by clicking an icon on a mobile application with ionic framework. For example I clicked the youtube icon on the Ionic framework app, it will open a browser and go to youtube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User Inappbrowser plugin in your project to open external links.
Plugin [Documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) .

General Steps:

1. add plugin using command 
    `ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`
2. Use this line where you want to open
   link

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://youtube.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```